# Loading a file with a name defined by attr

Tags: jquery

I have an image...

```
<img src="images/dut7_thumb.jpg" alt="images/dut7.jpg" filetoload="test.html"/>
```

I am trying to load the file "test.html" into the div with id "words" using...

```
$list.find('.st_thumbs img').on('click',function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $("#words").load("text/"+$this.attr('filetoload'));
});
```

...but filetoload is undefined?

How do I grab that file name?

Edit: Code was in the wrong place. Works fine now.

Comment: It should work (http://jsfiddle.net/bqD9K/)... are you sure your selector is correct? Better use HTML5 data attributes though.

Comment: [HTML5 introduces data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), which are pretty cool and applicable in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, but while I was checking I discovered I had nested it into a different load event. So the code works... when you put it in the right place! Thanks for the kick!

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. Maybe `$list.find('.st_thumbs img')` is wrong.

Look: http://jsfiddle.net/bBEDq/

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your entire html block

I was able to get it working with a little modification http://jsfiddle.net/sceVA/

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with the `$list`. Because your code seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/UVTu9/

Have you tried checking for the value of `$this`, try logging in into the console.